# The sharpening filter and edge detection kernel relationship?

Tags: image, image-processing, matrix, kernel, wikipedia

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking):

> (The sharpening filter) is obtained by taking the identity kernel and subtracting an edge detection kernel

Can someone explain to be how is that the case.
As for as I understand it, to achieve a sharpening image, you take the original image and add high-contrast edges to it.
They even take the example of the matrix:

[image: 2]

Should the matrix

```
0   -1   0
-1   4   -1
0   -1   0
```

be the edge detection kernel, according to [another Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) article? So, the math should be adding, not subtracting.

Anyway, I am a bit confused here and could use some help. Thank you!

Comment: **run the kernels** on some inputs. **watch** how they behave. -- it's about normalization/bias. the laplacian has a sum of 0, so its result is black on average, leaving only edges. the identity filter maintains absolute levels (sum 1, 1 is identity). the sum of both kernels is again 1, maintaining absolute levels. sure, you could add it instead of subtracting. that should give you a result of comparable brightness, but edges should look "different". btw, that [1, -4, 1] kernel is "upside down". a "mexican hat" is supposed to have a positive center. they tricked you with a double negative.

Comment: I've gone ahead and changed the wikipedia article because they talk of an "edge detection" kernel. the derivation of it causes it to be negative. it's the second derivative of a gaussian. makes sense that it'd be negative. the second derivative of a sine is a negative sine. so for an edge, it extracts the *negative* edge... so there, double negative.

Comment: I have updated the Wikipedia page on unsharp masking to make more sense. The sharpening kernel can be constructed as described earlier on the page, as "sharpened = original + (original − blurred) × amount". Introducing the Laplacian there was just pointless. I hope this clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is being pointed out, one needs to distinguish between first derivatives (edges) and second derivatives (ridges, peaks).

You don't talk about it but you link to an article on "unsharp masking". That is supposed to use a [difference of gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians)... which is *close to* a laplacian (... of gaussian). Not quite the same, but practically close enough.

That means you don't actually deal with edges but with ridges/peaks.

As for the kernels and their signs... Wikipedia is being mysterious and misleading as usual.

They *subtract* a laplacian because they have to. The laplacian has a *negative* response to peaks/ridges. Conceptually, you *do add* an edge/ridge detection filter... if it were one.

The kernel you see looks like an upside-down mexican hat. It's a "laplacian of gaussian". That means it's the second derivative of a gaussian kernel. As a second derivative, it responds **negatively** to a positive peak/ridge, e.g. of the gaussian.

Here's a plot of a gaussian and its first and second derivatives:

[image: gaussian and derivatives]

Since you'd expect a ridge/peak detection filter to have a *positive* response to a positive ridge/peak, you'd use the *negated* second derivative, and *add* that.

Look at these pictures:

1: [image: -1 +5 -1] 2: [image: source] 3: [image: +1 -3 +1]

1. the `[-1 +5 -1]` kernel, i.e. identity - laplacian = identity + filter
2. the picture itself
3. `[+1 -3 +1]` kernel, i.e. identity + laplacian = identity - filter

You see, #3 looks blurry because **some high frequencies were subtracted**.

Comment: well yes, edges aren't ridges. "edges" would be a generic term for high frequency components.

Comment: fine fine I'll edit everything.

Comment: I’ve fixed the 2nd Wikipedia page linked by OP. Let’s see how long that edit lasts…

Comment: It’s a thankless job, but I keep chipping at the misunderstandings and inaccuracies as best as I can. :)

Comment: Though a quick question of how to differentiate an edge detection and a ridge detection kernel? Because, I mean even someone who wrote the article may have mistaken it, or at least leave it mistaken and who know how many misunderstood the same thing. Is there a ridge detection kernel correspond to each edge detection kernel; and if so, what would be the equivalent ridge detection kernel of the Edge detection kernel from the Kernel (image processing) Wikipedia page that I linked? Thank you.

Comment: I don't get the question exactly, so I'll say some things that might be useful. -- don't worry too much. practically they all do something that "maintains" high frequency and "removes" low frequency, and everyone calls it "edge detection". if you wanted to learn more, you could investigate the distributive and commutative properties of convolution. take a differentiation kernel like `[+1 -1]`, apply it to an impulse (identity) like `[0 0 1 0 0]`, once, then once more. literally, calculate the result. use `np.convolve` if you like. watch what happens. try it on a gaussian.